# SonarQube failed to start in linux

Tags: sonarqube

I install and configure SonarQube like this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-1604/) but I can't start it properly. I see sonar.log and it was like this :

```
 --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.12.05 07:32:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2018.12.05 07:32:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.12.05 07:32:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2018.12.05 07:32:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.12.05 07:32:37 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.12.05 07:32:37 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.12.05 07:32:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.12.05 07:32:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar]: /usr/local/PA/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process3476754449645299131properties
2018.12.05 07:32:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.12.05 07:32:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.12.05 07:32:46 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2018.12.05 07:32:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I use non-root user to start it, but it doesn't help me. what could i do?

Comment: can you also put the output of your web.log here, it is normaly within you sonar-directory in the logs dir

Comment: @SimonSchrottner thank you. I found there that I need to upgrade mysql to newer version.

Comment: i added an answer for other people, if they look for information, i would highly appreciate if you mark it as "the answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log output is actually telling you where you can find more information.

Sonarqube is starting different processes

- es for elastic search
- web for the web layer
- compute engine
- sonar for managing all of them

when the sonar log is telling you, that one of those processes stopped, it is highly advised to take a look into the special logs for those.

within `<sonar-dir>/logs` you will find dedicated logs to each of the processes, and you can gather more information, most likely those will be sufficient enough to either solve the issue, or to ask for further help.

Comment: mine is failing on web process but it does not provide much information for debug issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **es.log** under `<sonarqube_home>/logs`. Most certainly there is an access issue on the Elasticsearch indices which can be fixed with chmod easily.