# Unable to Open Webpage in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I installed Sonarqube on my Ubuntu server. But am unable to View in web page. When i checked sonar.log,got below message. Can you please help me to overcome it and help in opening sonar webpage ?

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.12.21 14:17:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2018.12.21 14:17:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.12.21 14:17:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2018.12.21 14:17:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.12.21 14:17:14 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.12.21 14:17:14 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.12.21 14:17:20 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2018.12.21 14:17:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.12.21 14:17:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube failed to start in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632939/sonarqube-failed-to-start-in-linux)

Comment: Try to start SonarQube without any additional plugins. What version of SonarQube do you use? Have also a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731102/cant-run-sonar-server-caused-by-elasticsearch-cannot-running-as-root/47733598#47733598) question.

Comment: Hi..AM using SonarQube version 6.0. And moreover my dbms is oracle. Could you please help in creating sonar database for oracle ?...I have information only for mysql and needed steps for oracle .